# My Java is in gz format?

Tags: java, windows, zip, gz

I'm having problems downloading jre-8u101-windows....tar.gz java, because it's in .gz format instead of .exe, so when I run the installer it opens in my zip folder(Bandizip) please help

Thanks in advance,
MrWardy

Comment: huh... why don't you download the exe version then?

Comment: Oh @assylias (facepalm) I am so stupid, but it says Windows 64x offline, would that change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you that are wondering I did fix the problem and if anyone else is having this problem don't be an ideot like me, go to your java link, I use 64x java http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html I clicked "Windows x64 Offline". and make sure to click the link that says .exe, I was stupid and clicked the link saying .gz

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to google it? First link in google:
https://java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml

Comment: I have, and java does install but it installs as a .gz instead so when I open it it has to be opened as a zip, All I want to do is install java 64 bit :/